# Обсуждение такое професcии, как корректор

Tags: общие-вопросы

Добрый день! Я хотел бы услышать некоторую информацию об этой профессии. Как школьник, я уже начинаю строить некоторые планы на будущую жизнь, в том числе и выбираю профессию. Данная профессия меня заинтересовала: это мне нравится. Но что нужно, чтобы стать корректором? Не сочтите за труд, опишите. Если я раньше начну учиться, то смогу стать хорошим корректором, не правда ли?

Comment: "Такое профессии", как корректор, вам вряд ли подойдет.

Comment: Это уже опечатка :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы стать хорошим корректором (о профессии литературного редактора не говорим), нужно:

1. Выучить наизусть справочник Розенталя, научиться пользоваться словарями и не лениться перепроверять даже, казалось бы, знакомые слова.
2. Развивать концентрацию внимания.
3. Общаться с коллегами на профессиональные темы.
4. Максимально сохранять авторский стиль, то есть иметь представление о факультативных и вариативных нормах и исправлять бесспорные ошибки, а не навязывать тексту свои стереотипы.
5. Не злобствовать и не презирать тех, кто допускает ошибки, не считать себя самым умным и не ненавидеть учителя за то, что он обратился к тебе на "ты".
6. Активно практиковаться минимум 5 лет.

Answer (score 4):

Хотя в интернете написано, что это профессия, я бы не назвал это профессией. Это должность. Вряд ли есть заведения, где готовят именно корректоров. Достаточно хорошо владеть языком( на профессиональном уровне) , чтобы стать корректором. Филологи, журналисты  - все они могут стать корректорами.

Корректор
1. В издательствах и редакционно-издательских отделах вычитывает отредактированные рукописи и корректурные оттиски с целью устранения орфографических и пунктуационных ошибок, нарушения технических правил набора, недостатков смыслового и стилистического характера. Проверяет комплектность рукописей, правильность написания и унификации терминов, символов, единиц измерения, единообразие обозначений в иллюстрациях и тексте, правильность оформления таблиц, сносок, ссылок, формул, справочного аппарата, полноту библиографического описания, устраняет неправильную разбивку текста на абзацы, согласовывает с редакторами замеченные стилистические погрешности. При чтении корректурных оттисков проверяет соответствие набранного текста оригиналу, правильность набора текста, заголовков, примечаний и других выделяемых частей издания. В редакторском паспорте отмечает особенности вычитки рукописи.
2. Работает на полиграфических предприятиях. Вычитывает все виды литературы, вносит исправления специальными стандартными знаками в оттиски в соответствии с оригиналом и техническими правилами набора. Читает корректуру оттисков с типографского набора, содержащего иностранные слова, специальную терминологию, различные шрифтовые выделения, математические и химические формулы, нот с нотных досок или наштампованных на бумаге оригиналов нот и текстов музыкальных произведений.

Содержание труда: Сверяет текст с оригиналом и исправляет орфографические ошибки, допущенные наборщиками, верстальщиками, печатниками, проверяет подписи под рисунками, схемами, диаграммами, расстояние между буквами в строке.

Должен знать: Стандарт шрифтов, пробельных материалов, технические правила набора текста, таблиц, правила пунктуации, орфографии, наиболее употребляемые сокращения, математические и химические знаки, ноты и порядок их написания по Брайлю, правила пользования справочной литературой, словарями и справочниками, корректурные знаки.

Профессионально важные качества:
устойчивость внимания;
усидчивость;
собранность;
эрудированность;
острота зрения.

Квалификационные требования: Филологическое образование, полиграфические ССУЗы.

Медицинские противопоказания:
дефекты зрения;
нарушение координации движений рук;
аллергические заболевания.

Кстати, исправьте опечатку в вашем заголовке. Обсуждение такоЙ,( а не такоЕ)....

Comment: И  сколько  же  получает  такой  ценный  кадр ?

Comment: @bernard, кадр этот получает чуть ниже средней зарплаты по региону, если верить объявлениям

Comment: Вот  они  и  вымерли,  как  мамонты.

Comment: Корректор получает вполовину меньше журналиста, который допускает ошибки. Поэтому через полгода корректор выбрасывает справочники, начинает ненавидеть журналистов и уничтожать авторский стиль, а еще через полгодика, когда портится характер и появляется нервный тик, бросает всё и сам становится журналистом, так и не успев освоить прежнюю профессию.

Answer (score 3):

Корректоры - великие люди, им памятники надо ставить. Наверное, это призвание: настолько несовместимы знания и вложенный труд  с тем скромным вознаграждением, которым удостаивает их общество.

С другой стороны, корректор - это желательная ступень для редакторской должности, которая, с моей точки зрения, более интересная и творческая.

Comment: а вы, София, редактор?

Comment: Ну, скажем так: мне приходится иногда тесно общаться с ними.

Answer (score 3):

Для настроения. В 70-х годах нас, практикантов-журналистов, приехавших в "Новороссийскую правду", подряжали помогать корректорам, поскольку газета с какой-то радости (по-видимому, из-за пристального внимания к этому морскому порту после выхода в свет якобы написанной Брежневым "Малой земли")перешла на большой формат. Это при таком-то количестве населения и единственном большом заводе! В-общем, пахали и журналисты, и технические работники каждый день до 2 часов ночи. Я, помню, мученически возвела глубокой ночью глаза на нашу главную, казавшуюся мне тогда старенькой корректоршу и сказала, что если мы и дальше будем спать по три часа, а днем писать материалы, то скоро все дружно попадем в сумасшедший дом. А она мне в ответ: "Вы знаете, когда я пришла домой после первого рабочего дня в типографии (а это были сталинские времена), мама подала мне обед и села напротив. Я вдруг, пронзенная страшной мыслью, застыв с недонесенной до рта ложкой, спросила: "Мама, гигИпотам или гигЕпотам?!" Мама со вздохом сказала: "Гипопотам, детка. Ты кушай, кушай".

Вот что такое работа корректора. Только в нынешние невежественные капиталистические времена литературные редакторы выполняют в придачу к своей еще и корректорскую работу за одну зарплату, поскольку уловить разницу между ними хозяева СМИ не в состоянии. Впрочем, в России, может быть, дело обстоит иначе...

Comment: Увы, во многих изданиях обходятся и без корректора, и без литредактора. Тексты вычитывает "грамотный журналист", потому что считается, что эту работу может сделать любой носитель языка.